# Get formatted name of weekday id

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the id of a weekday, e.g. 3 (Wednesday) or 6 (Saturday).
How can I get the formatted weekday name of the user's current language?

This is what I've got so far, but I don't know how to set the date to the weekday I need.

```
getWeekdayShort(int weekday){
   DateTime date = DateTime.now();
   return DateFormat('E').format(date);
}
```

Comment: you mean you dont want `DateTime date = DateTime.now();`? You want to put the your own date instead of `now()`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, kind of - I don't have my "own date", just my "own weekday" - I thought I need to get it inside a DateTime object somehow in order to get it formatted automatically through DateFormat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

String localeName = "pt_BR"; // "en_US" etc.
initializeDateFormatting(localeName);
```

Use this:

```
static List<String> weekDays(String localeName) {    
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat(DateFormat.WEEKDAY, localeName);
    return [DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 4, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 5, 1),
      DateTime(2000, 1, 6, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 7, 1), DateTime(2000, 1, 8, 1),
      DateTime(2000, 1, 9, 1)].map((day) => formatter.format(day)).toList();
}
```

And then:

```
String getWeekday(int weekday, String localeName) => weekDays(localeName)[weekday];
```

Comment: You can use "Platform.localeName" to get the locale name dynamicaly